# Spring Boot (v1.5.1.RELEASE) and Spring ElasticSearch 3.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch

Are Spring boot v1.5.1 and Spring data elastic search 3.0.0 compatible.
We can only use Elastic search 5 if we have spring data elastic search 3.0.0 but the equivalent spring boot version 2.0 is not yet released.
So would like to know whether it could work with current spring boot version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You will end up in dependency hell if you try to get Spring Data Kay into Spring Boot 1.x — see also [Spring Boot application with current elasticsearch version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633048/spring-boot-application-with-current-elasticsearch-version/)

Either use the latest milestone of Spring Boot 2.0 (it should reach GA until the end of the year from what I've heard) or use Elastic's high level REST client and avoid any coupling to Spring Data.